# Navigating in JSF hierarchy up and down

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page hierarchy as shown below where everything starts with showing items in a primefaces datatable. For each item a `<p:link>` or `<p:commandlink>` is generated.
Click on an item's link should do a redirect to the editItem page with the item's id shown in the query string.

The edit page has a save and cancel button which should redirect back to the listItems page. 
The edit page has also a list of subItems, which are shown the same way as in the itemList. 
Click on a subItem's link should do a redirect to the editSubSubItem page with the item's id shown in the query string and click on save/cancel should redirect back to the origin editItem page.

Same behavior should be possible for the edit pages editSubItem, editSubSubItem, and so on... Means save/cancel should always redirect back one level in the hierarchy.

```
http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/listItems.xhtml

    http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/editItem&id=123
    -> save/cancel - back to listItems      

        http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/editSubItem&id=456
        -> save/cancel - back to editItem&id=123

            http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/editSubSubItem&id=789
            -> save/cancel - back to editSubItem&id=456
```

Is there an easy way to achive this kind of hierarchical navigation?

I'am using Primefaces 6.0 and JSF-2.2 on Wildfly-10.0.0.Final

Comment: maybe a [p:wizard](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml) ?

Comment: no, this is not an option, because i don't have the requirement that i do this step by step - so there is no need for next button.

Comment: What about history (-1)

Comment: `history(-1)` is a good tip, so i did the following:
 
Added `goBack()` javascript code to my page: `<script>function goBack() { window.history.go(-1); }</script>`
 
Cancel button looks like this and works as expected: 
`<p:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel" immediate="true" oncomplete="goBack()" />`

Comment: Save button looks like this and does not work as expected: 
`<p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="#{backingBean.save}" oncomplete="goBack()" />`

Using the save button this way `save` is called, but the "unsaved data" confirm dialog is also shown when input fields have been changed.
Addind `ajax="false"` to the save button, `save"` is also called, but `goBack()` does not fire!

Comment: My page also includes this detectUnsavedChanges.js javascript code, to avoid leaving the page without saving changes on input fields:

Comment: `$(function() { // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed. $(':input').on('change', function() { setConfirmUnload(true); }); // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly. $('form').on('submit', function() { setConfirmUnload(false); }); }); function setConfirmUnload(on) { var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?"; window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a `Stack<String>` object in the SessionMap, where i `push` the current page url before redirect to another page and `pop` the origin page on `close` of the page.

Comment: This sounds like it might cause a lot of confusion if the user has multiple tabs on your site open in their web browser...

Comment: I know this, but I didn't found a better solution yet ;-)